# Unusual checkbox is checked behavior

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="1" val="1" onclick="select_box(id);" name="main_vals[]">Box 1
<input type="checkbox" class="sub_checkbox_1" val="1.1" name="sub_vals[]">Sub box 1
<input type="checkbox" class="sub_checkbox_1" val="1.1" name="sub_vals[]">Sub box 1
<input type="checkbox" class="sub_checkbox_1" val="1.1" name="sub_vals[]">Sub box 1
<input type="checkbox" id="2" val="2" onclick="selec_boxt(id);" name="main_vals[]">Box 2
<input type="checkbox" class="sub_checkbox_2" val="2.1" name="sub_vals[]">Sub box 2
<input type="checkbox" class="sub_checkbox_2" val="2.1" name="sub_vals[]">Sub box 2
<input type="checkbox" class="sub_checkbox_2" val="2.1" name="sub_vals[]">Sub box 2
<input type="checkbox" id="3" val="3" onclick="select_box(id);" name="main_vals[]">Box 3
<input type="checkbox" class="sub_checkbox_3" val="3.1" name="sub_vals[]">Sub box 3
<input type="checkbox" class="sub_checkbox_3" val="3.1" name="sub_vals[]">Sub box 3
<input type="checkbox" class="sub_checkbox_3" val="3.1" name="sub_vals[]">Sub box 3
```

Javascript:

```
select_box = function(id) {
    if($('#main_checkbox_'+id).is(:checked)) {
        $('.sub_checkbox_'+id).each(function() {
           this.checked = true;
       });
    } else {
        $('.sub_checkbox_'+id).each(function() {
          this.checked = false;
      });
    }
}
```

Description:

As you can see, i have multiple checkboxes. My goal here is to check if the checkbox with id `main_checkbox_+id` is checked, then all the corresponding checkboxes with id `sub_checkbox_+id` should also be checked. Similarly, if the main checkbox is unchecked, the corresponding sub checkboxes should be unchecked. While this seems to be working for the majority of the main and sub checkboxes, there are a few which don't work as expected. With those few, the check to see if the main_checkbox is checked always yields false. I'm not sure why i am experiencing this behavior. I have many more checkboxes in the html in the same format. The ids are dynamically generated for all checkboxes.

Comment: my mistake, i didn't put the html in right. i made the change, please see the edited html and js.

Comment: Is `selec_boxt(id);` a typo?

Comment: when you pass `id` you pass `main_checkbox_1` to the function, non just `1`, please see my answer

Answer (score 2):

Get the attribute `val` by using `this.getAttribute('val')`

**HTML**

```
<input type="checkbox" id="main_checkbox_1" val="1" onclick="select_box(this.getAttribute('val'));" name="main_vals[]">Box 1
<input type="checkbox" class="sub_checkbox_1" val="1.1" name="sub_vals[]">Sub box 1
<input type="checkbox" class="sub_checkbox_1" val="1.1" name="sub_vals[]">Sub box 1
<input type="checkbox" class="sub_checkbox_1" val="1.1" name="sub_vals[]">Sub box 1
<input type="checkbox" id="main_checkbox_2" val="2" onclick="select_box(this.getAttribute('val'));" name="main_vals[]">
```

**jQuery**

```
select_box = function(id) {
       if($('#main_checkbox_'+id).is(':checked')) {
              $('.sub_checkbox_'+id).prop('checked',true);
        } else {
               $('.sub_checkbox_'+id).prop('checked',false);
        }
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/0eL8vame/1/)

But a better way to do this is using delegation and having containers like this

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <input type="checkbox" class="main_checkbox" val="1" name="main_vals[]">Box 1
    <input type="checkbox" class="sub_checkbox" val="1.1" name="sub_vals[]">Sub box 1
    <input type="checkbox" class="sub_checkbox" val="1.1" name="sub_vals[]">Sub box 1
    <input type="checkbox" class="sub_checkbox" val="1.1" name="sub_vals[]">Sub box 1
</div>
<div class="container">
    <input type="checkbox" class="main_checkbox" val="2" name="main_vals[]">Box 2
    <input type="checkbox" class="sub_checkbox" val="2.1" name="sub_vals[]">Sub box 2
    <input type="checkbox" class="sub_checkbox" val="2.1" name="sub_vals[]">Sub box 2
    <input type="checkbox" class="sub_checkbox" val="2.1" name="sub_vals[]">Sub box 2
</div>
<div class="container">
    <input type="checkbox" class="main_checkbox" val="3" name="main_vals[]">Box 3
    <input type="checkbox" class="sub_checkbox" val="3.1" name="sub_vals[]">Sub box 3
    <input type="checkbox" class="sub_checkbox" val="3.1" name="sub_vals[]">Sub box 3
    <input type="checkbox" class="sub_checkbox" val="3.1" name="sub_vals[]">Sub box 3
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$('.main_checkbox').on('change',function(){
    $(this).siblings('.sub_checkbox').prop('checked',this.checked);
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/9jy2s4tc/)

Answer (score 0):

try with this:

**HTML**:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="1" class="main_checkbox_1" val="1" onclick="select_box(id);" name="main_vals[]">Box 1
<input type="checkbox" class="sub_checkbox_1" val="1.1" name="sub_vals[]">Sub box 1
<input type="checkbox" class="sub_checkbox_1" val="1.1" name="sub_vals[]">Sub box 1
<input type="checkbox" class="sub_checkbox_1" val="1.1" name="sub_vals[]">Sub box 1
<input type="checkbox" id="2" val="2" class="main_checkbox_2" onclick="select_box(id);" name="main_vals[]">Box 2
<input type="checkbox" class="sub_checkbox_2" val="2.1" name="sub_vals[]">Sub box 2
<input type="checkbox" class="sub_checkbox_2" val="2.1" name="sub_vals[]">Sub box 2
<input type="checkbox" class="sub_checkbox_2" val="2.1" name="sub_vals[]">Sub box 2
<input type="checkbox" id="3" val="3" class="main_checkbox_3" onclick="select_box(id);" name="main_vals[]">Box 3
<input type="checkbox" class="sub_checkbox_3" val="3.1" name="sub_vals[]">Sub box 3
<input type="checkbox" class="sub_checkbox_3" val="3.1" name="sub_vals[]">Sub box 3
<input type="checkbox" class="sub_checkbox_3" val="3.1" name="sub_vals[]">Sub box 3
```

**JS**:

```
select_box = function(id) {
    console.log(id);
       if($('.main_checkbox_'+id).is(":checked")) {
              $('.sub_checkbox_'+id).each(function() {
                     this.checked = true;
               });
        } else {
               $('.sub_checkbox_'+id).each(function() {
                      this.checked = false;
                });
        }
}
```

with `id` you pass the whole ID to the function, not just the number 1,2,3..so I changed the ID and added the class to the main checkbox, correcting the JS by consequence.

you can see a working fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/s7s61doo/2/).

Comment: In your fiddle, clicking Box 2 won't check the sub checkboxes.

Comment: actually, my mistake again, this is what i have in my html. looks like i need to pay more attention when writing my question. sorry!

Comment: @chridam: there was a typo in the javascript call, I corrected it